# I need to pass value to another ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocr

The program read texts from image files then shows it on the website. But I also want to create a pdf file from that text. I found a way to create pdf but I can not pass text value to this pdf creation action. I'm using Tesseract OCR and Syncfusion.Pdf.Net.Core NuGet packages in my project. First one for reading text from images. Latter is for creating pdf from the text.

Here is my HomeController.cs code

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ProcessFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");

    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "tessdata"), "eng", EngineMode.Default))
    {
        using (var image = new Bitmap(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            using (var page = engine.Process(image))
            {
                IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();
                model.Text = page.GetText();
                model.MeanConfidence = page.GetMeanConfidence();

                return View("Index", model);
            }
        }
    }
}

public ActionResult CreateDocument()
{
    //Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    //Add a page to the document
    PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

    //Create PDF graphics for the page
    PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;

    //Set the standard font
    PdfFont font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.Helvetica, 14);

    //Draw the text
    graphics.DrawString("", font, PdfBrushes.Black, new Syncfusion.Drawing.PointF(0, 0));

    //Saving the PDF to the MemoryStream
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    document.Save(stream);

    //If the position is not set to '0' then the PDF will be empty.
    stream.Position = 0;

    //Download the PDF document in the browser.
    FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
    fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = "Output.pdf";
    return fileStreamResult;

}
```

Comment: *"but I can not pass text value to this pdf creation action"* - why not? You havent described your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good, if you move PDF creation logic into separate class (or even BLL project). Project of creation PDF could be long, you might want to make it background.

```
public class PdfCreator : ICreator // Not best naming :)
{
    public byte[] Create(string data) // Or you could pass your own class, dictionary, etc...
    {
        // Your PDF creation logic from public ActionResult CreateDocument()
    }
}

// To easily test and inject
public interface ICreator
{
    byte[] Create(string data);
}

// And in you Controller class
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICreator _pdfCreator = null;

    public HomeController(ICreator creator)
    {
        // You will receive it here from Dependency Injection framework or just initialize
        _pdfCreator = creator ?? new PdfCreator();
    }

    // Use it
    public ActionResult CreateDocument()
    {
        byte[] pdf = _pdfCreator.Create("My specific text");
        // Your logic goes here
    }
}
```

It could be slightly bigger than your code, but this let you to unit test your controller, which creates PDF, with different scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Invoke CreateDocument Action from view using Html.Action and pass your model as parameter:

```
// View returned by ProcessFile
@Html.Action("CreateDocument", Model)

// Get model from view
public ActionResult CreateDocument(IndexViewModel model)
{
    // ...
}
```